# Access two different RootDN with Single Admin Kerberos Principal

Tags: kerberos, openldap, sasl

as an admin, I've been trying to make 2 different RootDN accounts login with a single kerberos account lately.

### I have two different **rootDN** and **password**

```
-D "cn=admin,cn=config" 
-D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
```

---

when I login via Kerberos like;

```
kinit ldap/admin
```

I want to use both with "ldap/admin" principal;

```
-D "cn=admin,cn=config" -W -Y GSSAPI
-D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -W -Y GSSAPI
```

I have applied the relevant commands to achieve this, but I can only access one ROOTDN, but I want to operate on both. How can I do this without olcAccess?

```
olcAuthzRegexp: {0}"uid=ldap/admin,cn=example.com,cn=gssapi,cn=auth" "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com'
olcAuthzRegexp: {1}"uid=ldap/admin,cn=example.com,cn=gssapi,cn=auth" "cn=admin,cn=config'
```

I try access two Different RootDN with Single Principal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-D` and `-W` options only apply to simple binds. For SASL bind, you need to use `-X` to specify the SASL "authorization identity":

```
$ ldapwhoami -Y GSSAPI -X "dn:cn=admin,cn=config"
```

However, `olcAuthzRegexp` only defines the *default* authzid (i.e. the regexps are used for authnid transformation to authzid) and is not what you want for `-X`.

In order to be allowed to specify custom identities, I believe you need to use `olcAuthzPolicy` in combination with either `authzTo` on your own authnid entry, *or* `authzFrom` on the entry that you intend to impersonate. (Yes, the rootDN can have an actual entry.)

For example, with `olcAuthzPolicy: any`, the entry would need to have:

```
dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
authzFrom: {0}dn.exact="uid=ldap/admin,cn=example.com,cn=gssapi,cn=auth"
```

If you are not able to create a real entry at `cn=admin,cn=config` (the config backend will most likely not support this), you will need to use the opposite approach with `authzTo` instead:

1. Define `olcAuthzRegexp` to map your "cn=gssapi,cn=auth" DN to **one** real DN that exists in the main database backend:

   ```
   olcAuthzRegexp: {0}"uid=ldap/admin,cn=example.com,cn=gssapi,cn=auth" "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com"
   ```

   Verify that your connections are authorized as this DN by default:

   ```
   $ ldapwhoami -Y GSSAPI
   dn:cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
   ```
2. Actually create the DN, with its `authzTo` attributes listing the DNs that it is allowed to impersonate (authorize as):

   ```
   dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com
   authzTo: {0}dn.exact="cn=admin,cn=config"
   ```
3. Set `olcAuthzPolicy` to `both` or `from`, then use the `-X` option to specify the DN that you want to assume:

   ```
   $ ldapwhoami -Y GSSAPI -X "dn:cn=admin,cn=config"
   dn:cn=admin,cn=config
   ```

**Make sure users are not allowed to edit `authzTo` on their own entries, or any other entry.** Use olcAccess to prevent this.

Comment: Not it is not working like that; output is

SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind: Insufficient access (50)
        additional info: SASL(-14): authorization failure: not authorized

Comment: Yes, see the edit I just added regarding that.

Comment: I applied; << authzTo: dn.regex:^cn=admin,cn=config$ >> on <<  dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com >> but same error,

Comment: What DN do you get from a plain `ldapwhoami -Y GSSAPI` without any authz options?

Comment: <pre><code>
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
SASL username: ldap/admin@EXAMPLE.COM
SASL SSF: 256
SASL data security layer installed.
dn:cn=admin,cn=config<br/>

Comment: Okay, so you first need to remove the second olcAuthzRegexp (the {1} cn=config one), because you have set authzTo on the `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com` entry, so you need to have that as your "default" identity. (You may need to restart slapd after removing authzRegexp rules...)

Comment: (Also, I remember Stack Overflow developers saying that advanced Markdown formatting _deliberately_ does not work in comments (only single-backtick inline markup does); they want to encourage people to edit things into their main post instead.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help master!!! I was able to reach my goal. @user1686

Comment: by the way, ı want to ask, can u give any example about olcAccess rule to disable "authzTo" and "authzTo" , for example only "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" user can use "authzTo/authzTo" attributes and denied all other users?

Comment: Something along the lines of `to attrs="authzFrom,authzTo" by * auth`. (The rule needs to grant `by * auth` at least; you can't use `by * none`.) You don't need to explicitly grant access to the rootDN, as it always has full access due to being the rootDN, so this is an example of granting access to group members instead:  `to attrs="authzFrom,authzTo" by group="cn=Admins,o=Example" manage by * auth`.